# Filtering or removing array objects from the DTO class object based on a condition in .net

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-core

I have an API which gives response in the below format :

```
[
    {
        "OrderId" : "Order1"
        "filterOrder": [
            "ABC",
            "XYZ"
        ],
        "Details": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "value": 100,                
                "filterDetails": [
                    "Apples",
                    "Oranges"
                ]                
            },
            {
                "id": 2
                "value": 200,                
                "filterDetails": [
                    "Banana",
                    "Blank"
                ]                
            }
        ]   
        
    },
    {
        "OrderId" : "Order2"
        "filterOrder": [
            "PQR",
            "Blank"
        ],
        "Details": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "value": 100,                
                "filterDetails": [
                    "Apples",
                    "Peaches"
                ]                
            },
            {
                "id": 2
                "value": 200,                
                "filterDetails": [
                    "Banana",
                    "Mango"
                ]                
            },
        ]   
        
    }
]
```

I received the response and deserialized it into a model class ( same structure as above).
My requirement here is to remove all those objects from the response where the filters are mentioned as "Blank".
In the above example , the output should be something like this :

```
[
    {
        "OrderId" : "Order1"
        "filterOrder": [
            "ABC",
            "XYZ"
        ],
        "Details": [
            {
                "id": 1
                "value": 100,                
                "filterDetails": [
                    "Apples",
                    "Oranges"
                ]                
            }
        ]   
        
    }
]
```

I have tried few examples after searching online , but couldn't proceed further.

```
var item = responseObject.Find(x=>x.filterOrder == "Blank");
responseObject.Remove(item);
```

But this gives compilation error.Can anyone help me in filtering the data as per requirement. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: FilterOrder is an array but you are comparing it with string... that doesn't work. Use contains if you want to check if array has the item you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your JSON example contains errors (missing commas)
   i separated in 2 steps (dont know if you need to remove blanks from children)

```
void Main()
{
    string i = "[{\"OrderId\":\"Order1\",\"filterOrder\": [ \"ABC\", \"XYZ\" ], \"Details\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"value\": 100, \"filterDetails\": [ \"Apples\", \"Oranges\" ] }, { \"id\": 2, \"value\": 200, \"filterDetails\": [ \"Banana\", \"Blank\" ] } ] }, { \"OrderId\": \"Order2\", \"filterOrder\": [ \"PQR\", \"Blank\" ], \"Details\": [ { \"id\": 1, \"value\": 100, \"filterDetails\": [\"Apples\", \"Peaches\" ]}, { \"id\": 2, \"value\": 200, \"filterDetails\": [\"Banana\",\"Mango\"]}]}]";
    var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(i);

    //first level
    lst.Where(w => w.filterOrder.Contains("Blank"))
    .ToList().ForEach(fe => {lst.Remove(fe);});
        
    //details level
    lst.ToList().ForEach(fe =>
    {
        fe.Details.Where(ww=> ww.filterDetails.Any(a => a.Contains("Blank")))
            .ToList().ForEach(details =>
            { 
                fe.Details.Remove(details);
            });
    });
            
    lst.Dump();
    
}

    public class Detail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public List<string> filterDetails { get; set; }
    
    public Detail(){
        filterDetails = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class Root
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<string> filterOrder { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    
    public Root(){
        Details = new List<Detail>();
        filterOrder = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

the result would be

[image]

the short version:

```
lst.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains("Blank"));
    lst.ForEach(fe => {fe.Details.RemoveAll(r=> r.filterDetails.Contains("Blank"));});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of going about it.

If you know for a fact that there will be only one item that will contain Blank, then use the following,

```
List<Order> rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(jsonStr);
var itemToRemove = rootobject.Find(x => x.filterOrder.Contains("Blank"));
rootobject.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Note that this will only remove the "first" occurence and leave the rest of the items in that array with Blank in the response. This is because `Find` only finds the first occurence. [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-5.0)

To remove "all" items from the response that has the word Blank in it, you can use the `RemoveAll` method or `Where` clause to create a new list without any occurences of Blank in filterOrder.

```
rootobject.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains("Blank"));

//or 
rootobject = rootobject.Where(x => !x.filterOrder.Contains("Blank")).ToList();
```